# How to export and deploy a nextjs project without disabling API routes?

Tags: reactjs, api, routes, next.js, vercel

I got very confused when it came to deploying my project, i used nodejs and mongodb for the backend.
So when i wanted to deploy the project, i didn't know how to build it. I have read about static site generation and server side rendering, but i dont know which one to choose.
I ran a npm run build which disabled the api routes (which is exactly what i dont want to happen)  in my project with this configuration:

```
"scripts": {
"dev": "next dev",
"build": "next build && next export",
"start": "next start",
"lint": "next lint"
```

}

PS: i didnt use getServerSideProps or getStaticProps or anything because my website doesn't fetch any data at build time.

Comment: [Several Next.js features are not supported](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/static-html-export#unsupported-features) when using `next export`, including API routes. If you want API routes you have to use `next build && next start`, as they require a running server to work.